# "Комар носа не подточит"

Tags: фразеология

Так говорят, когда речь идет о том, что не к чему придраться. А почему комар? И почему ему нужно точить нос? Откуда пошло это выражение?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысл поговорки такой: работа настолько идеальна, что в ней нельзя найти ни малейшего изъяна, куда бы комар мог просунуть свой тонкий нос.

Точить — это «изъесть» , «изгрызть». Слово «подточить» в отношении комара имело значение «покусать», что видно из старой русской песни: Мушки, блошки не кусают, не едят, комарики не подтачивают.

Также существовали поговорки:  «Люди схвастают — иглы не подточишь, мы соврем — целое бревно подсунешь» !  «Между женским ДА и НЕТ ни иголки не просунешь». «Между мужем и женой нитки не проденешь».

http://otvet.mail.ru/question/47035024

Answer (score 3):

Комариный "нос" - самая тонкая вещь, с которой, видимо, могли сравнить хорошо выполненную тонкую работу. "Подточить" - скорее всего в смысле "сколько нос не затачивай - а тоньше (чем работа) он не будет". Ну или в значении "не просунет" (сравните с жуком-*точильщиком*) - в общем-то тот же самый образ тончайшего "носа".

Comment: Думаю,  что  просто  в  смысле:  не  просунет.

Comment: >Думаю, что просто в смысле: не просунет.  
  
Нет, однозначно сказать нельзя. См. Софья. Хотя у неё тоже есть чему возразить - все в кучу. Но по поводу значения "точить" (как одного из возможных) я с ней согласен.

Answer (score 2):

Комар  носа  не  просунет. Или, лучше, не  воткнёт.  Можно  провести  связи  и  с  глаголом  тыкать,  и  с  существительным  точка.

Answer (score 1):

Одно из возможных пониманий поговорки (в свете многозначности глагола *подточить/подтачивать*).
Глагол *подточить* - сов. вид от *подтачивать* (тачать), т.е. сшивать два края ткани особым плотным швом. Поговорка *комар носу не подточит* также существовала в вариантах с булавкой и иголкой. Вполне вероятно, что имелась в виду тонкая, аккуратная, ювелирная работа без малейшего изъяна, примером которой мог служить ровный шов ***тачки*** - плотный, без просветов.

> П. И. Мельников-Печерский. На горах. Книга вторая (1875-1881)
> Только в том и разница, что теперь берут поискуснее ― **не подточишь иголочки.**

Answer (score 1):

> Выражение «Комар носа не подточит» имеет значение: «не к чему
>   придраться» . Оно достаточно молодое, но успело несколько раз поменять
>   свое значение. В начале ХХ века Владимир Маяковский приложил руку к
>   этой фразе, причем немного исказил исконный смыл — так и получилось:
>   «придраться не к чему — без сучка, без задоринки» . Собственно говоря,
>   сегодня мы, произнося «комар носа не подточит» , это и имеем в виду. А
>   что же было раньше?
>
> Слово «подточить» понимали как «покусать» . Собственно говоря, это
>   видно из старой доброй русской песенки:
>
> ...Мушки, блошки не кусают, не едят,
>
> комарики не подтачивают.. .
>
> Известный русский филолог В. М. Мокиенко провел исследование и
>   выяснил, что буквально за 150 лет официального существования выражения
>   в нем переплелись три значения:
>
> 1. не к чему придраться
> 2. кусает комар, что есть, точит нос
> 3. враг точит зуб
>
> В какой-то период времени каждый из этих смыслов был основным. А
>   причина смены смысла идет от нечеткого понимания глагола «точить,
>   подтачивать» . Точить — это «изъесть» , «изгрызть» . Еще «точить нос»
>   говорят, когда речь идет о запахе. В общем, погрузилась я в
>   размышления о нелегкой доле комара и увидела, что и в старые времена,
>   когда выражение «комар носу не подточит» не было записано ни в каких
>   словарях, люди видели смысл такой: «дело сделано безупречно, и даже
>   самый проницательный человек не найдет зацепочек и шероховатостей — то
>   бишь «комар носа не подточит» !
>
> Существовало еще выражение «под добрую сваху комар носа не подточил
>   бы» . Причем раньше даже более популярно было выражение про иголку.
>   Оно с тем же смыслом, но так говорили, в основном, о вранье: «Люди
>   схвастают — иглы не подточишь, мы соврем — целое бревно подсунешь» !
>   Так говорили на Смоленщине. Еще говорили — «между женским ДА и НЕТ ни
>   иголки не просунешь» . Еще — «между мужем и женой нитки не проденешь»
>   .
>
> В принципе, не так много времени пролетело, но произошла
>   диалектическая замена: иголка превратилась в комара, а «поддеть» — в
>   «продеть» и «подточить» . Кстати, так появилось и еще одно
>   промежуточное значение — теснота! Во всяком случае, так было в
>   Белоруссии. Где даже существовало выражение «комар носом не подлезет»
>   . То есть «иголки некуда воткнуть» . Так что крылатое выражение в
>   пословицах и поговорках существовало еще в далекие времена и имело
>   разнообразные значения — в зависимости от места, времени и стиля жизни
>   людей.
>
> Ну, а когда в XIX веке филологи впервые решили внести фразу в словари,
>   там появилось значение «иглы не заточишь» . Так решили объединить все
>   имеющиеся понятия и попытались сделать это как можно более лаконично.
>   С этого момента и возникла двусмысленность в выражении «точить» и
>   словарное закрепление крылатого выражения «комар носу не подточит».

https://otvet.mail.ru/question/47035024

Мне нечего добавить к этой версии. Да, не очень документально, но других-то правдоподобных и вовсе не наблюдается.

Хотя вот [тут](https://books.google.ru/books?id=5c3itE4HFDcC&pg=PT16&lpg=PT16&dq=%D0%92%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82.&source=bl&ots=6_0EwCMguW&sig=TpUsr8tDC2uotiEOArpYRTm2iXw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTvsGFupnTAhWmAJoKHVWIAHEQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82.&f=false) утверждается иное. Вкратце: "подточить" рассматривается как синоним "подсунуть", что сомнительно, да и объясняет не до конца. Разве комариный "нос" - инструмент для "просовывания"?

Answer (score 0):

Я это понимаю так: сделано до такой степени идеально, плотно, чётко, что даже тонюсенький комариный "носик" нигде, ни в какую щель, зазор(между составляющими конечной работы) не пролезет."

Answer (score 0):

"Не подточит" в том смысле, что комариный нос настолько тонок, что подточить его, чтобы он стал еще тоньше (для того чтобы пролез), просто нет никакой возможности. Это наименьший диаметр из всех возможных. Даже Левша не сделает тоньше.